# How do I publish an application with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework-6

I have an application I was tasked with creating for a school project and one of the requirements was that it should be able to communicate with a Microsoft SQL Server database using Entity Framework 6.

I'm done developing the app, but when I click on publish and it generates a setup file, the app won't run on another computer that's mine. I thought Entity Framework would generate a native database automatically but I guess I was wrong.

Can anyone help me publish the application such that it is able to run on another computer. Sorry if this matter seems trivial but I could not find a solution that worked anywhere.

Comment: Sharing relevant code (your data context) increases your chances of receiving a qualiy answer for your question.

Comment: If you're using a SQL Server database, then **you must** install SQL Server on that target machine as well - or have access to a central SQL Server from that target machine. Just shipping an app with EF **doesn't** make that other PC know how to use and deal with SQL Server databases....

Comment: I have similar issue. Can someone look at my data context class and say what is wrong? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64742840/wpf-net-core-published-as-self-contained-app-doesnt-run-on-another-machine-wit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your Data Context (class that inherits from [`DbContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)) it sounds like you need to set an [`IDatabaseInitializer<TContext>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.idatabaseinitializer-1?view=entity-framework-6.2.0).

**Try adding this line of code which sets the [`IDatabaseInitializer<TContext>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.idatabaseinitializer-1?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) to [`CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<TContext>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.createdatabaseifnotexists-1?view=entity-framework-6.2.0):**

```
Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists< YourContextClass >());
```

This code should only be executed once before creating an instance of your Data Context (ideally during application initialization).

Comment: Even if I include that code in my Data Context class which is CustomerDBModelEntities for me, I get the following error

```Unhandled exception. Network related or instance specific error occured while ```establishing a connection to the server

Comment: This error is typically related to your database connection. Check your [connectionStrings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files#working-with-application-configuration-files) to ensure you have a valid connectionString.